# paring html string to object with error messages when failed

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm working on comparing 2 html string that can show messages when somethings wrong, so I'm looking for javascript library like htmlparser2 or any that can show messages when parsing failed like e.g.

```
let string = '<div> somethings </div>';
parseString(string); // return array or object

let string = '<div> somethings <div>';
parseString(string); // return messages e.g. missing close tag "<div>" line: 5

let string = '<dv> somethings </div>';
parseString(string); // return messages e.g. failed "<dv>" line: 3
```

i'm now using jquery DOM to parse html but it doesn't show errors when missing any close tag or wrong spelling at close tag
I haven't found any library that handle cases like above example.

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/validator/validator

Comment: @Unknown thanks for that but it's javascript, so i got an idea instead.